# How do I take a number of bit strings from a text file and put them into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, function, methods, bitstring

I ultimately want to test a few bit strings for randomness. To start I think I need to make a method that can read a text file of bit strings and store them in an array.

```
    private static int[] ReadDataFile(string s)
    {
        List<int> theList = new List<int>();
        string[] sArray;
        string bs;
        StreamReader inputfile = new StreamReader("bitstring.txt");
        do
        {
            bs = inputfile.ReadLine();
            sArray = bs.Split(new char[] { });
            for (int i = 0; i < sArray.Length; i++)
            {
                theList.Add(int.Parse(sArray[i]));
                Console.WriteLine(sArray[i]);

            }
        } while (inputfile.EndOfStream);
        inputfile.Close();

        return theList.ToArray;

    }
```

I am getting an error on the last line that says

> Cannot convert methid group ToArray to non-delegate type int[].

How do I resolve this? Also is this the right approach?

Comment: how big is your file that you read? How is your file structured? This would help to answer your last question

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing the brackets at `ToArray` (needs to be `ToArray()`)

Answer (score 0):

`ToArray` is a method. You need to call it like one.

In the last line put parentheses behind the call like you do in a usual
method call:

```
return theList.ToArray();
```